# Relative import doesn't work : ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package

Tags: python-3.x, oop, import, relative-import

This are the files:

parent_directory:

[image]

parent_directory/ecommerce:

[image]

parent_directory/ecommerce/payments:

[image]

What I'm trying to do is to use a relative import in products.py in order to import database.py. I know that I can just write `import database` but I want to learn relative imports. I've also tried to import main.py from the top level directory, parent_directory, but that doesn't work either so I thought I'll just try to do the easiest relative import possible and that is, importing a file from the same package.

This is the code for products.py inside parent_directory/ecommerce:

```py
from .database import Database

class Product:
    pass
```

And this is the code from the database.py file inside parent_directory/ecommerce:

```py
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import products

    x = products.Product()

class Database:
    pass

print("file : {0:<35} || name : {1:<20} || package : {2:<20}".format(
    str(__file__).split("\\")[-1],
    str(__name__),
    str(__package__),
))
```

I tried several things like:

- executing products.py with -m like `python -m products.py`
- creating a py venv
- adding **all** and **package** inside the files.

Here is my **init**.py file from parent_directory/ecommerce:

```py
__all__ = ["database", "products"]
__package__ = "ecommerce"
```

No matter what I do, I always get this error: `ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package`. I know that this question has been asked before. I've tried many things out but nothing worked. Do you have any idea how to fix this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem.
I have to be outside the package and use -m and instead of using / to send the path, I have to use . instead so :

`python -m parent_directory.ecommerce.products`

This will fix the problem but I have to **execute this line outside the top-level package** ( in my case, the top level package is parent_directory ).

```
# Inside products.py
from .database import Database # works
from ..main import SomeRandomClass # works

class Product:
    pass
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found a way to import files from parent directories, since it's very easy to import them from sub-packages by using absolute imports.

```
# inside parent_directory/ecommerce/products.py trying to import parent_directory/main.py
import sys
import os

current_file = os.path.realpath(__file__)
current_dir_ecommerce = os.path.dirname(current_file)
parent_dir_parent_directory = os.path.dirname(current_dir_ecommerce)
sys.path.insert(0, parent_dir_parent_directory)

import main # works
```

I just added the parent directory to sys.path.